# Logmein Hamachi on Ubuntu: Logging in..... Failed

Tags: linux, logmein

My hamachi works well in a house with own internet connection.
However, where I live (a student residence with shared internet and owned by another one), my hamachi does not work.

When I type:

```
sudo hamachi login
```

it says:

```
logging in..... failed.
```

What could be the problem? I found the following log file, but I don't understand it. I hope it helps!

```
04.30 17:00:18.848 ses: << msg_helo ..
04.30 17:00:18.959 ses: io error, send, 111
04.30 17:00:18.959 ses: error 3, retryable yes
04.30 17:00:19.071 ses: go_offline, keep_tunnels 0, login_on_relaunch 0, actual state 1 ..
04.30 17:00:19.172 ipc: 0176f640 del client
04.30 17:00:49.141 ipc: user paul allowed
04.30 17:00:49.141 ipc: 0175fba0 add client 182
04.30 17:00:49.142 cfg: save()
04.30 17:00:49.464 cfg: hks: [0] [2048]
04.30 17:00:49.464 cfg: hkc: [0] [2048] [2048]
04.30 17:00:49.465 tcp: laggy read, breaking out..
04.30 17:00:49.465 ipc: 0175fba0 del client
04.30 17:00:49.476 ipc: user paul allowed
04.30 17:00:49.476 ipc: 01744190 add client 183
04.30 17:00:49.477 cfg: save()
04.30 17:00:49.611 cfg: hks: [0] [2048]
04.30 17:00:49.611 cfg: hkc: [0] [2048] [2048]
04.30 17:00:49.611 sys: connmgr_go_online, reconnect 0
04.30 17:00:49.823 tcp: laggy read, breaking out..
04.30 17:00:49.823 ses: on_conn_state(connected, 0x0)
04.30 17:00:49.824 ses: select conn mode 'dns lb'
04.30 17:00:49.824 ses: go_offline, keep_tunnels 1, login_on_relaunch 0, actual state 4 ..
04.30 17:00:50.047 sys: go_online, reconnect 0
04.30 17:00:50.159 ses: resolving hamachi-dc.logmein-gateway.com ..
04.30 17:00:50.173 ses: resolving hamachi-list.10.logmein-gateway.com ..
04.30 17:00:50.174 ses: resolve list -> -1, fall back
04.30 17:00:50.174 ses: select conn mode 'web lb'
04.30 17:00:50.282 ses: requesting http://secure.logmein.com/myrahost/list_hamachi.aspx?weighed=1&os=linux ..
04.30 17:00:50.282 web: start web request 'http://secure.logmein.com/myrahost/list_hamachi.aspx?weighed=1&os=linux'
04.30 17:00:50.341 web: http get 126 bytes
04.30 17:00:50.341 web: http download complete, total bytes 126
04.30 17:00:50.341 ses: selected (52.211.50.139, 6580)
04.30 17:00:50.341 ses: selected 01 connection type
04.30 17:00:50.449 ses: resolving 52.211.50.139 ..
04.30 17:00:50.672 ses: connecting to 52.211.50.139:12975 ..
04.30 17:00:50.673 ses: connection is established
04.30 17:00:50.784 ses: control connection is bound to 192.168.168.148
04.30 17:00:50.784 ses: << msg_helo ..
```